# Grade build issue with the latest version of androidx room libraries version 2.6.0

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, android-room

The latest release of libraries will make by grade build error.

I have to roll back the following libraries to get rid of these errors below:
libraries with versions that work w/o errors:

```
    implementation ("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.2")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.2")
```

```
 annotationProcessor("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")
    ///kapt('androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2')
    ksp ("androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.2")
    testImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:2.5.2")
```

I got these errors before I roll back these libraries:

```
error message: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'kotlin.sequences.Sequence com.google.devtools.ksp.processing.Resolver.getPackagesWithAnnotation(java.lang.String)'
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspRoundEnv.getElementsAnnotatedWith(KspRoundEnv.kt:107)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.CommonProcessorDelegate.processRound(XBasicAnnotationProcessor.kt:100)
    at androidx.room.compiler.processing.ksp.KspBasicAnnotationProcessor.process(KspBasicAnnotationProcessor.kt:62)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension$doAnalysis$6$1.invoke(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:291)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension$doAnalysis$6$1.invoke(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:289)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.handleException(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:394)
    at com.google.devtools.ksp.AbstractKotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.doAnalysis(KotlinSymbolProcessingExtension.kt:289)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:123)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.analyzeFilesWithJavaIntegration$default(TopDownAnalyzerFacadeForJVM.kt:99)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:257)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler$analyze$1.invoke(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:42)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.messages.AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.analyzeAndReport(AnalyzerWithCompilerReport.kt:115)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.analyze(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:248)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:88)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.compiler.KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.compileModules$cli$default(KotlinToJVMBytecodeCompiler.kt:47)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:168)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.jvm.K2JVMCompiler.doExecute(K2JVMCompiler.kt:53)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:100)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLICompiler.execImpl(CLICompiler.kt:46)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.cli.common.CLITool.exec(CLITool.kt:101)
    at org.jetbrains.kotlin.daemon.CompileServiceImpl.compile(CompileServiceImpl.kt:1486)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:360)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:712)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:587)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:828)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:705)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:399)
    at java.rmi/sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:704)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: same issue when upgrade to 2.6.0, and not reported yet: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=status:open%20componentid:413107&s=created_time:desc

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Update:**

You have to update your ksp version and then you can update your room version:

```
plugins {
     id 'com.google.devtools.ksp' version '1.9.0-1.0.12' apply false
}
```

**Previous answer:**

This version is not compatible with `ksp` currently. `for now` you can change it to `kapt`:

```
implementation 'androidx.room:room-ktx:2.6.0'
implementation 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.6.0'
kapt 'androidx.room:room-compiler:2.6.0'
```

also you need to use kapt schemaLocation config:

```
defaultConfig {

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation": "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }
```